# Show a specific case in the URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, uppercase

I know is not recommended, but how do I make my URL always show a specific case e.g. myWebsite.com, that if one type mywebsite.com, the URL will always change to myWebsite.com.

I have tried several htaccess found in the internet, but all of them change everything to lowercase.

Again, I know it is not recommended, that is not the what I am asking, but how can it be done. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know htaccess, but this may be partly controlled by your client's web browser/app, and not by you.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^myWebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://myWebsite.com/$1 [P]
```

[Another answer](https://serverfault.com/a/744666/369810)